# OpenCL How to write vector of floats to image2d_t

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, opencl, gpgpu

For an OpenCL program I write I need to make computations on grayscale images. These grayscale images are stored in .pgm format and I read them into my program as vectors of floats.

As I understand the image2d_t memory object, every pixel is encoded as an OpenCL vector data type with 4 components, e.g. float4 as in my case, where components 1 to 3 encode the colour value in the 3 colour channels R,G,B and the fourth component encodes either luminance or alpha. Hence I tried blowing up an existing image to read it into an image2d_t memory object like so:

```
std::vector<float> A(256,0.0);
std::vector<float> A_img(1024, 0.0);

for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
{
    A_img[4*i] = A[i];
    A_img[(4*i)+3] = 1;
}
```

Later in the process of copying this vector to an image2d_t object, the little endianness of my device might cause components 1 and 4 to be switched. I am not sure on that.

However, I am not able to obtain back the image when writing this image to my GPU memory, having a kernel read it, writing it to an output image and reading it back from GPU memory. A minimal working example (which are always kind of long for OpenCL) would be as follows:

```
#define CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#define CL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#if defined(__APPLE__) 
#include <OpenCL/cl2.hpp>
#else 
#include <CL/cl2.hpp>
#endif
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{
    // Set up platform, device and context
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
    cl::Device default_device;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
    
    if (platforms.size() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "No OpenCL platform found, check installation!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    platforms[0].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);
    
    if (devices.size() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "No devices found in platform, check installation!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    default_device = devices[0];
    cl::Context context(default_device);
    
    std::ifstream program_file("read_write_image.cl");
    std::string program_string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(program_file), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    cl::Program::Sources source { program_string };
    cl::Program dummy_program(context, source);
    if (dummy_program.build()!=CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << "Error building: " << dummy_program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(default_device)<< std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    cl::Kernel kernel(dummy_program, "read_write_image");
    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, default_device);
    
    // Set up dummy grayscale image
    std::vector<float> A(256, 0.0);
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        A[i] = 255.0f - i;
        std::cout << A[i] << "  ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    // Blow up to float4 array
    std::vector<float> A_img(1024, 0.0);
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        A_img[4*i] = A[i];
        A_img[(4*i)+3] = 1;
    }
    std::vector<float> B_img(1024, 0.0);
    
    cl::ImageFormat grayscale(CL_R, CL_FLOAT);
    cl::Image2D Input_Image(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, grayscale, 16, 16);
    cl::Image2D Output_Image(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, grayscale, 16, 16);
    
    std::array<cl::size_type, 3> origin {0,0,0};
    std::array<cl::size_type, 3> region {16, 16, 1};

    queue.enqueueWriteImage(Input_Image, CL_TRUE, origin, region, 0, 0, &A_img[0]);

    kernel.setArg(0, Input_Image);
    kernel.setArg(1, Output_Image);
    
    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(16,16), cl::NullRange, NULL); 
    queue.enqueueReadImage(Output_Image, CL_TRUE, origin, region, 0, 0, &B_img[0]);

    for(int i=0; i<1024; i++)
    {
        std::cout << B_img[i] << "  ";
    }   
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The kernel code (to be placed in the file "read_write_image.cl") is the following:

```
__constant sampler_t sampler = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE|CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP|CLK_FILTER_LINEAR;

__kernel void read_write_image(read_only image2d_t input_image, write_only image2d_t output_image)
{
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    int j = get_global_id(1);
    float tmp = read_imagef(input_image, sampler, (int2) (i,j)).x;
    write_imagef(output_image, (int2) (i,j), (float4) (tmp,0,0,1));
}
```

This minimal working example produces a 16x16 image A, which, interpreted as a grayscale image, starts in the top left corner with a white pixel and ends in the bottom right corner with a black pixel, and the read back image B on my system is completely black, i.e. just zeroes. At which point do I go wrong in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first:

- The little endianness of my system does not revert the order of the coordinates in the process of reading the array into an image
- Even though read_imagef and write_imagef work with float4s, not every image_2dt is a float4-array. Removing the "blow-up" parts from the code and just using the regular buffers makes the example a working example. However, support (for the image format) seems to be platform dependent, on my Macbook it won't work with the changes, on my AMD graphics card it works

Here the modified host code:

```
#define CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#define CL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#if defined(__APPLE__) 
#include <OpenCL/cl2.hpp>
#else 
#include <CL/cl2.hpp>
#endif
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{
    // Set up platform, device and context
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
    cl::Device default_device;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
    
    if (platforms.size() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "No OpenCL platform found, check installation!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    platforms[0].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);
    
    if (devices.size() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "No devices found in platform, check installation!" << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    default_device = devices[0];
    cl::Context context(default_device);
    
    std::ifstream program_file("read_write_image.cl");
    std::string program_string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(program_file), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    cl::Program::Sources source { program_string };
    cl::Program dummy_program(context, source);
    if (dummy_program.build()!=CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << "Error building: " << dummy_program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(default_device)<< std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    cl::Kernel kernel(dummy_program, "read_write_image");
    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, default_device);
    
    // Set up dummy grayscale image
    std::vector<float> A(256, 0.0);
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        A[i] = 255.0f - i;
    }
    // Set up empty target image
    std::vector<float> B(256, 0.0);
    
    cl::ImageFormat grayscale(CL_R, CL_FLOAT);
    cl::Image2D Input_Image(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, grayscale, 16, 16);
    cl::Image2D Output_Image(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, grayscale, 16, 16);
    
    std::array<cl::size_type, 3> origin {0,0,0};
    std::array<cl::size_type, 3> region {16, 16, 1};

    queue.enqueueWriteImage(Input_Image, CL_TRUE, origin, region, 0, 0, &A[0]);

    kernel.setArg(0, Input_Image);
    kernel.setArg(1, Output_Image);
    
    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(16,16), cl::NullRange, NULL); 
    queue.enqueueReadImage(Output_Image, CL_TRUE, origin, region, 0, 0, &B[0]);

    for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        std::cout << B[i] << "  ";
    }   
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The kernel does not change.